# Real-time scheduler class conflicts with aodv network

Tags: omnet++, inet

Because there is a extrouter in my aodv network that contains an ExtLowerEthernetInterface, I need to set the scheduler-class=" inet:: RealTimeScheduler "in the ini file.". However, after this, the aodv node does not transfer the received RREQ message upward.  Therefore, the entire aodv network was destroyed.  "Is there any way to do this? I'm puzzled now. Thank you very much for your help

```
scheduler-class = "inet::RealTimeScheduler"
*.extRouter.numEthInterfaces = 1
*.extRouter.eth[0].typename = "ExtLowerEthernetInterface"
*.extRouter.eth[0].device = "veth0"
```

package inet.examples.aodv.Drone;

```
import inet.common.scenario.ScenarioManager;
import inet.networklayer.configurator.ipv4.Ipv4NetworkConfigurator;
import inet.networklayer.ipv4.RoutingTableRecorder;
import inet.node.aodv.AodvRouter;
import inet.physicallayer.wireless.unitdisk.UnitDiskRadioMedium;
import inet.visualizer.common.IntegratedVisualizer;
import inet.node.inet.Router;
import ned.DatarateChannel;


network Drone
{
    parameters:
        int numHosts;
        @display("bgb=944.376,745.56");

    types:
        channel pppline extends DatarateChannel
        {
            datarate = 100 Gbps;
        }


    submodules:
        radioMedium: UnitDiskRadioMedium {
            parameters:
                @display("p=100,200;is=s");
        }
        configurator: Ipv4NetworkConfigurator {
            parameters:
                config = xml("<config><interface hosts='*' address='145.236.x.x' netmask='255.255.x.x'/></config>");
                @display("p=100,100;is=s");
        }
        routingTableRecorder: RoutingTableRecorder {
            parameters:
                @display("p=100,300;is=s");
        }
        visualizer: IntegratedVisualizer {
            parameters:
                @display("p=100,30");
        }
        scenarioManager: ScenarioManager {
            parameters:
                script = default(xml("<scenario/>"));
                @display("p=100,400;is=s");
        }
       host[numHosts]: AodvRouter {
            parameters:
                @display("i=device/pocketpc_s;r=,,#707070");   
            gates:
                pppg[1];
        }
        extRouter: Router {
           parameters:
               ipv4.routingTable.routingFile = "extRouter.mrt";
                @display("i=device/router_l;p=98.868,509.31998;is=s");
                
            gates:
                pppg[21];

        }

    connections allowunconnected:
        for i=0..numHosts-1 {
           host[i].pppg[0] <--> pppline { @display("ls=,0"); } <--> extRouter.pppg[i];
        }
}
```

Comment: Could you add NED file of your network to the question?

Comment: I edited it above. "But I'm sure it's because the scheduling class is set to RealTimeScheduler, because I only added a code scheduler-class=" inet:: RealTimeScheduler "to the ini file of the example/aodv in the INET library, resulting in a change in the entire aodv network."